# @font-face rendering thick

Tags: fonts, css, font-face

using standard fontsquirrel based @font-face mark up.. the font is rendering on the thick side. below is a screenshot demonstrating the font in a few different ways. top is photoshop's render, second is chrome's render of the same font (obviously much thicker), and third is chrome's render of a similar font, which is also rendering kind of chunky.

http://cl.ly/0e3b2t1N0U2e003h322O

Tried using `font-weight:lighter` with no avail.. is there any trick to lighten it up?

thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

added a few things to the h1 markup (where the fontface rule was applied).

`font-weight:normal;`  fixed a weird doubling thing that happened in iOS

`-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` handled the thick render

Comment: it is -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;

Comment: `font-weight: normal;` worked for me in Chrome on Win7, all my fonts were rendering doubly thick!

Comment: the firefox equivalent
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above, I had an issue with a Font Squirrel created font kit and noticed the rendering a little bolder than I initially had seen too.

Sometimes the default font weight for headers (h1, h2, etc) in the user agent (browser) is set to 800.
If you use a CSS reset, they often fix the default to something around 500 or 400.

Read the following article for more information:

http://css-tricks.com/watch-your-font-weight/